# Email app: how can I change the sender address?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, email

I'm using the Android Email app and IMAP/SMTP (not the Gmail app). How can I change the sender ("From") e-mail address? I know how to switch between accounts when sending mail, but I can't find a setting for the e-mail address of each account. Currently, when I send an e-mail, only my username appears in the "From" field (which makes it pretty hard to reply to my e-mails).

The version of the Email app is 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't senarvi, it's a fairly basic setting left out by the android developers to push people towards using a gmail account.

You can setup the gmail account to 'pull' email from another and also send using a different address (set these up online, rather than through the device).

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the account name?

*NOTE: This is for Email 4.2.* Instead of having something like `geffchang`, change it to `geffchang@email.com`. In the Email app: `Settings > Added accounts: [account] > Common settings: More settings > Account name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than single account in Android Email App(hope you know how).
When you are inbox you at top you can find a drop down list with all your accounts names.
You can choose one which you want to sent mail from.

Then just compose that mail and send it.

Comment: I have several accounts and, as I said, I know how to switch between them when sending mail. The question is, how to set the e-mail address for a particular account.

Comment: you are adding an account by setting an email address. And configuring it based on that email account. How can you configure an email address and send from different email with that configuration? or you can edit an account with desired mail address.